# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DBEngine::prepare()

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to create a function that whenever i click the button the function inserts something in the DB. Im creating that using PDO but it doesn't seem to work and its giving me an error. If anyone could help please to point me in the right direction. `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DBEngine::prepare() line 87`

DB_Config :

```
<?php
    class   DBEngine
        {
            public  $con;
            public  $errors;
            public  function __construct($host="mysql10.000webhost.com",$db = "a6150953_test",$user="a6150953_henri",$pass="hajvan123")
                {
                    try {
                            $this->con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
                        }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                          $this->errors['connect']['message']    =   $e->getMessage();
                          $this->errors['connect']['error_code'] =   $e->getCode();
                        }
                }

                public  function Fetch($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                    $this->errors['fetch'][]    =   $query->errorInfo();

                    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                            while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    $array[]    =   $rows;
                                }
                        }

                    return (isset($array) && $array !== 0 && !empty($array))? $array: 0;
                }

            // Simple write to db method
            public  function Write($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                    $this->errors['insert'][]   =   $query->errorInfo();
                }
        }

// To use/initialize
$con = new DBEngine(); ?>
```

actions

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('php/classes/db_config.php');
include_once('php/classes/class.user.php');

$follow = new User($con);

echo $is_uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
echo $action = $_GET['action'];
echo $def_uid = $_GET['u_id'];

if($action == "follow"){
    $follow -> insert($is_uid, $def_uid);
}
if($action == "unfollow"){
    $follow -> delete($is_uid, $def_uid);
}

?>
```

functions (inlcuded just the two functions not the whole page)

```
public function insert($is_uid, $def_uid){
        $sql        =   "INSERT INTO follow (user_one, user_two) VALUES (:user_one, :user_two)";
        $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $q -> execute(array(':user_one'=>$is_uid, ':user_two'=>$def_uid));

        return $q;
    }
    public function delete($is_uid, $def_uid){
        $sql        =   "DELETE FROM follow WHERE user_one = '$is_uid' AND user_two = '$def_uid'";
        $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: i don't see what's the need of a wrapper for `pdo` with some class which have the same methods.

Comment: help pls? solution. i am fairly new to PDO

Comment: Prepare isnt a method on your DBEngine object. Most probable $this->db is your DBEngine instance. $q = $this->db->prepare($sql); then doesnt work.

Comment: @RonaldSwets so how do i fix it. Can you point me pls

Comment: Which is the line that is throwing the error? (Of which snippet)

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ its the first function. (insert Function)

Comment: Ok, writing answer now

Comment: Easiest way to fix (although not recommended) is using $this->db->con instead of $this->db in the insert function. Better would be implementing a prepare method in DBEngine OR extending the Write function with parameters used in the prepare statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prepare` is a PDO method, not a method in your `DBEngine` class. You can define the method like this:

```
public function prepare($query) {
    return $this->con->prepare($query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man. It worked. My stats went into db. quick and fairly easy to understand solution